# How do i replace a 4x4 square box with a 4x4x21/8 box

Tags: electrical

The purpose is to hold more wires inside it and not be in violation of NEC. Using an extension would work, but i feel more comfortable with a deeper box. The problem is the 1/2" conduits that feed into the box is set for the 4x4. By replacing it with the 4x4x21/8 the holes are set further back and this would protrude the box out by 1/2", unless i rip the wall and try to offset those conduits which would be a major work problem. What do you guys normally do? This is inside the house. The extension ring seems to be my only option.

Comment: I think you are confusing a 4" x 2 1/8" deep box with a 4 11/16" square box. Which do you want to use?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to replace a 4"x4"x1.5" box with a deeper 4"x4"x2 3/8" box. Definitely need some more information before anyone can help evaluate other options than the ones you have identified. Minimally, we need the actual box fill that you require. Also, what changed to make you need more space? If it's a bulkier receptacle, you could add another old work box above/below/adjacent to the current box to serve the new receptacle. Pictures are worth a thousand words.

Comment: It has 12 wires in a 4x4x1.5 square. Like your ideas . Will have to attach pictures when i come home. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Be selective about which deep box you use.   Many of them offset the knockouts toward the back, so you can use the same offset bends you're used to doing.

Comment: See master electrician link. That box will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have room to use a 3 1/2" deep box, it has some holes that line up, or you could also cut your own holes if necessary. Here's a link for an example.

http://www.graybar.com/store/en/gb/super-deep-4-in-square-outlet-box-25457161#{Box Depth (Inches):3-1/2 in.}&{Side Knockouts (Inches):1/2 and 3/4 (12)}&{Bottom Knockouts (Inches):1/2 and 3/4 in.}&{Bracket:No Bracket}

Comment: Your link can solve the problem.